# What is the differences between the term 'object' and 'instance' in a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, definition

I cannot distinguish the two terms.
How about you?

Answer (score 2):

Every **object** is an **instance** of a type. The word *instance* is used instead of *object* when describing member scope (i.e., *static* vs. *instance*). The word *object* is usually used instead of *instance* when referring to the target of a reference (e.g., a variable or field).

Answer (score 1):

For many (probably most) purposes, there's no real difference. You can get into some fringe areas, such as C, which defines essentially anything (but a function) that has an address as being an "object" -- but of course, nothing in C is an "instance" the way that term is typically used (i.e., an instance of a class). Then again, it's all a matter of definitions -- as long as you and whomever you're talking with agree on what the words mean, it doesn't matter a whole lot whether you call something an "instance" or an "object" or a "blarfle".

Answer (score 0):

Object is a more general term. Anything is an object, it may not an instance of particular type. For most common purposes, those terms can be interchanged especially in the context of a program.